# Insert into MySQL from R

Tags: mysql, r, dbi, rmysql

I am using DBI package to insert data to MySQL. Here is the code:

```
ch <- DBI::dbConnect(MySQL())
dbSendQuery(ch, 'set character set "utf8"')
dbSendQuery(ch, 'SET NAMES utf8')
for (i in 1:nrow(test)) {
  query <- paste0("INSERT INTO trade_data VALUES('0', '", test[i, 1], "', '",
                  test[i, 2], "', ", test[i, 3], "')")
  dbSendQuery(ch, query)
}
```

The problem is in 3td column, which is numeric, but have `NA` values. When loop comes to row which has `NA` value it returns an error:

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :    could not run statement:
>   Unknown column 'NA' in 'field list'

I tried to change NA to NaN, "NULL", and some other types, but nothing works. If I change NA to 0 it works.

Comment: Check if the 3rd column equals to NA and convert to 0 if it does.

Comment: Btw, there seems to be an extra single quote before the closing )

Answer (score 2):

Consider the programming industry standard of parameterization for any application layer like R that runs SQL. With this approach, you avoid any needs of string interpolation or messy quote enclosures. R's DBI standard has several ways, one of which is [`sqlInterpolate`](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#interpolation-by-hand):

```
# PREPARED STATEMENT (NO DATA) QMARKS REQUIRED BUT NAMES CAN CHANGE
sql <- "INSERT INTO trade_data (Col1, Col2, Col3, col4) 
        VALUES (?param1, ?param2, ?param3, ?param4)"

ch <- DBI::dbConnect(MySQL())
dbSendQuery(ch, 'set character set "utf8"')
dbSendQuery(ch, 'SET NAMES utf8')

for (i in 1:nrow(test)) {
  # BIND PARAMS
  query <- sqlInterpolate(conn, sql, param1 = "0", param2 = test[i, 1], 
                          param3 = test[i, 2], param4 = test[i, 3])
  # EXECUTE QUERY
  dbSendQuery(ch, query)
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it returns an error: ` Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 101.2, 101.2, `
0.05, 101.2, 101.2, 101.2, 101.2, 250000, 253000, 02.01.2008)' at line 1 `

Comment: Afer I change "" to NA, it have problems with dots inside characters:  Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.2008)' at line 2

Comment: You appear to have more than 4 columns in *trade_data* which this `INSERT` assumes if you omit explicit columns. Be sure to include **all** columns you intend to update data: `INSERT INTO trade_data (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...) VALUES(...`

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable changing NA to 0, then your best bet is to do the following.

`test[is.na(test)] <- 0`

This will replace all NAs in the data.frame `test` with 0. You can do the same and change to string 'NULL' if you please as well.

`test[is.na(test)] <- 'NULL'`

If you are looking to replace only a column, you can do the following:

`test$col3[is.na(test$col3)] <- 0`

Comment: I don't want to set NA to zero because than I don't know which are 0 and which Na.

Comment: Change to string 'NULL'

Comment: For `NA`s they want the substring `NULL` to be in the query string between `VALUES` commas. Not `'NULL'`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it right. I had to change "" to "NULL" and NA to NULL, and then used ifelse statement in insert. Like this:

```
ch <- DBI::dbConnect(MySQL())
dbSendQuery(ch, 'set character set "utf8"')
dbSendQuery(ch, 'SET NAMES utf8')
test[test == ""] <- "NULL"
test[is.na(test)] <- "NULL"
for (i in 1:nrow(test)) {
  query <- paste0("INSERT INTO trade_data VALUES('0', '", test[i, 1], "', ",
                  ifelse(test[i, 2] == "NULL", test[i, 2], paste0("'", test[i, 2], "'")), ", ", 
                  ifelse(test[i, 3] == "NULL", test[i, 3], paste0("'", test[i, 3], "'")), ", ",
                  # test[i, 3],", ", 
                  test[i, 4], ", ",
                  test[i, 5], ", ",
                  test[i, 6], ", ", test[i, 7] , ", ",
                  test[i, 8], ", ", test[i, 9] , ", ",
                  test[i, 10], ", ", test[i, 11] , ", '",
                  test[i, 12], "')")
  dbSendQuery(ch, query)
}
DBI::dbDisconnect(ch)
```

Comment: Your question doesn't mention wanting empty strings to become nulls. In SQL the empty string is not null. (Only Oracle equates the empty string to null, it's not standard SQL.)

Comment: Some people have a hard time distinguishing between the empty string (`""`) and `NULL` - hint: there's a difference ;)